# UITextField position and size depending on screen size

Tags: swift, constraints, textfield

When the screen size changes, the textField moves out of its place. How to attach it in the same place depending on the screen size?
Grey background of the textField for clarity.

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
    scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
    
    containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
    containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
    containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
    containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor),
    containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
    
    plateImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 50),
    plateImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
    plateImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
    plateImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: plateImage.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.6785162287),
    
    inputTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: plateImage.topAnchor, constant: 25),
    inputTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: plateImage.leadingAnchor, constant: 80),
    inputTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: plateImage.trailingAnchor, constant: -28),
])
```

Here is my scrollView, containerView and texField. I think all variables are fine. Aren't they?

```swift
private lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    
    var view = UIScrollView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 37 / 255, green: 40 / 255, blue: 47 / 255, alpha: 1)
    view.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    view.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    view.autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight
    view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    view.bounces = true
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
    }()
    
private lazy var containerView: UIView = {
    
    var view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 37 / 255, green: 40 / 255, blue: 47 / 255, alpha: 1)
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
    }()
    
private lazy var plateImage: UIImageView = {
    
    var view = UIImageView()
    view.image = UIImage(named: "plate")
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
    }()
    
public lazy var inputTextField: UITextField = {
    
    var view = UITextField()
    view.textAlignment = .center
    view.textColor = .black
    view.tintColor = .clear
    view.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: 155)
    view.keyboardType = .numberPad
    view.addButtonsToKeyboard(search: #selector(self.resignFirstResponder))
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
    }()
```

Here is my controller full code.

```
final class PlatesView: UIView {
    
    weak var delegate: PlatesViewDelegate?
    
    init(subscriber: PlatesViewDelegate?) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        self.delegate = subscriber
        addSubView()
        setupLayout()
        setupButtonAction()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func addSubView() {
        
        addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(plateImage)
        containerView.addSubview(inputTextField)
    }
    
    private lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        
        var view = UIScrollView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 37 / 255, green: 40 / 255, blue: 47 / 255, alpha: 1)
        view.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        view.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
        view.bounces = true
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        
        var view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 37 / 255, green: 40 / 255, blue: 47 / 255, alpha: 1)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var plateImage: UIImageView = {
        
        var view = UIImageView()
        view.image = UIImage(named: "plate")
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    public lazy var inputTextField: UITextField = {
        
        var view = UITextField()
        view.textAlignment = .center
        view.textColor = .black
        view.tintColor = .clear
        view.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: 155)
        view.keyboardType = .numberPad
        view.addButtonsToKeyboard(search: #selector(self.resignFirstResponder))
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    private func setupLayout() {
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
            containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
            
            plateImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 50),
            plateImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            plateImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            plateImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: plateImage.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.6785162287),
            
            inputTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: plateImage.topAnchor, constant: 33),
            inputTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: plateImage.leadingAnchor, constant: 80),
            inputTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: plateImage.trailingAnchor, constant: -28),
            inputTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 130),
        ])
    }
    
    private func setupButtonAction() {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set clipsToBounds to scroll, container and plateImage? scrollView.clipsToBounds = true, containerView.clipsToBounds = true, plateImage.clipsToBounds = true

Comment: Just added clipsToBounds to scroll, container, plateImage. Nothing happened. TextField still moves out.

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: Give me pls a full code of this controller

Comment: @Woop Code added)